# Locating Multiple Points on Mutlipes routes by a Unique ID

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, linear-referencing, route, grouping

I'm trying to get a "MEASURE" for Points along a route.  I need ARCGIS10 Desktop Linear Referencing tools or other application to use a unique identifier to match the Lines in the route to points scattered offline.  I'm trying to avoid running the Linear Referencing Locate along route tool separately for over 80 unique Point/Routes.

## I've Tried the following:

Buffer the Points to Intersect the line -> Run the Locate along route tool selecting the Parent ID for the Output - > In the Output Table and using Field Calculator, Set up an Python "If/Else" Statement:

```
def myCalc (ID1,ID1_Orig):
  if(ID1==ID1_Orig):
    return 1
  else:
    return 0
```

Codebook - Sort=
    myCalc(!ID1!,!ID1_Orig!)

Then Deleting all returns with "0" in the "Sort" column.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the route and points with the same id before you run the locate tool?

Comment: Yes, Using ArcGIS for Desktop . . . There are Multiple Lines with their own unique ID's and Points also; I'm trying to avoid querying for each individual point/Line instance . . . Sounds like you do understand my concern.